# js prototype class.create coexistance between variables in subclass and superclass

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, prototype-programming

Very simply put, I have lots of classes that share variables and have their own variables. So I created a super class called Resource and many subclasses. The problem is that I want to be able to set and get any value. I simplified the code, but this is what i can't do. Keep in mind that there are many many variables in each class, icluding the superclass and I dont want to redefine the class each time.

```
var MySuperClass = Class.create({
    initialize:function () {
        var a;
        var b;
        var c;  
        //Getters
    this.getA=function () {
        return a;
    };
    this.getB=function () {
        return b;
    };
    this.getC=function () {
        return c;
    };

    //Setters

    this.setA=function (val) {
        a = val;
    };
    this.setB=function (val) {
        b = val;
    };
    this.setC=function (val) {
        c = val;
    };
    //end Setters   
},
sub:function () {
    return this.getA()-this.getB()-this.getC();
}
});

var MyClass = Class.create(MySuperClass, {
  initialize:function () {
        var d;
        var e;
           //Getters
    this.getD=function () {
        return d;
    };
    this.getE=function () {
        return b;
    };
    this.getC=function () {
        return c;
    };

    //Setters

    this.setA=function (val) {
        a = val;
    };
    this.setB=function (val) {
        b = val;
    };
    this.setC=function (val) {
        c = val;
    };
    //end Setters   
},
add:function () {
    return this.getA()+this.getB()+this.getC()+this.getD()+this.getE();
}
});

function test() {
 myclass=new MyClass();
 myclass.setA(1);
 myclass.setB(0);
 myclass.setC(3);
 myclass.setD(2);
 myclass.setE(3);
 var result=myclass.add();
 var result2=myclass.sub();
 alert(result+' '+result2);
}
```

Of course the subclass is overriding the superclass initialize so the values cannot be accessed. How can I initialize subclass variables and superclass variables so that they can both be accessed from the test function?

As always, thank you for your help

Comment: I found this old discussion wich relates to private variables in prototype classes. Not much help, it just states that it's not an easy matter and that to accomplish it prototype is an ugly matter.
[Implement private variables for classes](https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886-prototype/tickets/152). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing var variables , that means it will be available only inside the initialize function. Make those variable as class level variable by initializing like the following

```
initialize:function () {
    this.a;
    this.b;
    this.c;
```

},

```
getA:function () {
return this.a;
```

}

This way all these variable will be available in base class as well as super class.

Comment: This is the way I'm currently working, but I would like the variables to be private and only accessed through gets and sets. If I declare them as "this" I'm able to access the variables directly.